# What's actually happening when I iterate through Transform

Tags: unity-game-engine

Something that has been bothering me for a long time is why do the following lines of code have the same results.

Code 1:

```
Transform[] childs = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
foreach(Transform child in childs) { Debug.Log(child.name); }
```

Code 2:

```
foreach(Transform child in gameObject.transform) { Debug.Log(child.name); }
```

This is actuallly a pseudo-code, I didn't really test it but should be enough to explain.

My question is, what's happening on Code 2 ? Is gameObject.transform actually an array of Transform ? Why doesn't Code 2 print the name of the parent gameObject ?

Maybe this is something very simple and obvious I'm just overlooking but I can't make it out right now.

Comment: When you wonder "Is gameObject.transform actually an array of Transform" the best place to look is the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) It is a single Transform that is part of that GameObject. If your hierarchy had many children then `GetComponentsInChildren` could return many Transform objects belonging to many GameObjects.

Comment: This is accomplished using the IEnumerable interface. [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-6.0)

Comment: I did have a quick look at the documentation but couldn't find anything relevant, anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Transform implements the IEnumerable interface.  This interface is what allows the use of the `foreach` keyword.

```
public partial class Transform : Component, IEnumerable
```

The IEnumerable interface requires implementation of the `GetEnumerator()` method.  The enumerator is responsible for keeping track of the position in the underlying collection and indicating if there are more items to be iterated over.

This is implemented in `Transform` below

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new Transform.Enumerator(this);
}

private class Enumerator : IEnumerator
{
    Transform outer;
    int currentIndex = -1;

    internal Enumerator(Transform outer)
    {
        this.outer = outer;
    }

    //*undocumented*
    public object Current
    {
        get { return outer.GetChild(currentIndex); }
    }

    //*undocumented*
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        int childCount = outer.childCount;
        return ++currentIndex < childCount;
    }

    //*undocumented*
    public void Reset() { currentIndex = -1; }
}
```